# How to refresh random number in template after clicking the same link?

Tags: angular

I tested this snippet:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  random;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.onSameUrlNavigation);
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload'


    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
      this.random = Math.random();
    });
  
  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

}
```

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Router Sample</h1>
  <div class="navLinks">

  <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About Us</a>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  <div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This is a template child about:

```html
<h1>random : {{random}}</h1>
<p>
  about works!
</p>
```

How can I generate a new random number after clicking on the same link?
if I click the same link "about us", the random number is the same.

test with: NavigationEnd

```js
//app modlule
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
//about.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
 
  random;
 
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    console.log("click route again");
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
      this.random = Math.random();
    });
   }
 
  ngOnInit() {

 
  }
 
}
```

I try this snippet with NavigateEnd, ne random is no change ? may be i forgot another something ?

Comment: Kindly make an online simulation of your code using the link- https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to router events, check if the event is a navigation end, and do your thing.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
    this.random = Math.random();
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz of that ?

Comment: how do stackblitz ??

Comment: Oh my bad, you don't actually change route. Add this at the top of your constructor : `this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';`.